# Properties of boolean operators in Python

Tags: python, boolean

If I have an `if` statement that uses `and` and `or`, can I do something like:

```
if (a=0 or x=2) and y=1:
```

or do I have to repeat myself and do:

```
if a=0 and y=1 or x=2 and y=2:
```

Comment: Why don’t you write a test to assert whether they’re equivalent?

Comment: Yes you can. And next time try it yourself or look into docs because this is one of the first things you'd learn... In addition, your statements are not equivalent: y=1,  y=2..

Comment: The comparative operator is `==` not `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Both will work fine (well, after fixing the bug at the end of the second version). But beware, that's not how comparisons are written! do this:

```
if (a == 0 or x == 2) and y == 1:
```

Or equivalently:

```
if (a == 0 and y == 1) or (x == 2 and y == 1): # NOT y == 2 as you wrote
```

Notice that `==` is the equality operator - a single `=` means *assignment*.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean algebra exhibits many of the properties of typical algebra. Distributivity of `and` over `or` is one of the [Monotone laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws) and is stated so:

```
x∧(y∨z)     =   (x∧y)∨(x∧z)
```

In your case:

```
(y == 2) and ((a==0) or (x==2)) = ((y==2) and (a==0)) or ((y==2) and (x==2))
   x      ∧  (  y    ∨     z  )   (    x    ∧    y  ) ∨  (  x     ∧    z)
```